# SQL regex quantifier operand invalid on postgres 9.5.16, works on 9.6.12

Tags: postgresql

I have a `SQL` query:

```
select
  concat('PL', (regexp_matches( mt_line.info_to_owner, '(?<=~31)(.*?)(?=~)'))[1]) AS "sender",
  (regexp_matches( mt_line.info_to_owner, '(?<=38)(.*?)(?=$)'))[1] AS "receiver"
from b.mt_line AS mt_line;
```

It works fine when i execute it on my local database, postgresql version 9.6.12, but it does not work on test database - postgres version 9.5.16.

I get following error there:

```
[2201B] ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

If i change this query to:

```
select
  concat('PL', (regexp_matches( mt_line.info_to_owner, '.*'))[1]) AS "sender",
  (regexp_matches( mt_line.info_to_owner, '.*'))[1] AS "receiver"
from b.mt_line AS mt_line;
```

Then it works fine on both versions of postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lookbehind` was introduced in postgres 9.6, see:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-matching.html

Check `Table 9-17. Regular Expression Constraints`

```
(?<=re) positive lookbehind matches at any point where a substring matching re ends (AREs only)
(?<!re) negative lookbehind matches at any point where no substring matching re ends (AREs only)
```

Postgres 9.5 does not have these options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-matching.html
Check
`Table 9-15. Regular Expression Constraints`.